# Facebook open graph- share a poem instead of an article

Tags: facebook, web, share, facebook-opengraph

My website shares poems, stories and articles.
This is an example of an open graph of a poem.

```
  {
   "id": "905716739487689",
   "application": {
      "id": "728278247279506",
      "name": "mypen",
      "url": "https://he.mypen.net/"
   },
   "created_time": "2015-04-08T10:48:04+0000",
   "description": "My complexity, my life is yours. You have me in the morning as i get out of bed. You have me in the night as i go to sleep.  My complexi...",
   "image": [
      {
         "height": 408,
         "type": "image/jpeg",
         "url": "https://d331rn7syke6mg.cloudfront.net/random/red/32/7/612.jpg",
         "width": 612
      }
   ],
   "is_scraped": true,
   "site_name": "MyPen.net",
   "title": "My Complexity",
   "type": "article",
   "updated_time": "2015-05-27T07:40:27+0000",
   "url": "https://en.mypen.net/read.php?ID=123",
   "data": {
      "section": "Poems"
   }
}
```

The problem is, that when a user shares a poem, facebook tells it's an article. I've read in other places that i should set og:type to article, but it's doesnt seems right:

[image]

Is there any way to set the open graph to say "Eran Shmuel shared a poem on mypen"?

Or do I have to change og:type to "website" for poems and stories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom OpenGraph obejects and actions. Have a look at the guidelines at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom

> There are a few basic components to creating custom Open Graph stories:
>
> - An app namespace for publishing and reading actions and objects
> - A custom object
> - A custom action
> - An Open Graph story configured for publishing

In your case I think you need to set up the first two points, and use the share dialog for the sharing of the object.

Comment: Thanks you!
Would it change the number of views of my posts?
Because I've heard og:type="article" is recommended